# SQL query to pull a single row for each date and the associated max date_time stamp

Tags: sql

I have a table with a date column which displays temperature data for a given date as well as another column which indicates the date and time that this data is generated as follows:

[Raw Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4QrF.png)

I would like a query which pulls a single row of data for each `DATE_STAMP` data that correlates to the most recent `DATA_UPDATE_DATETIME` data.

The result for should be as follows:

[Desired Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B1id.png)

I've tried several queries which attempts to utilize partitioning or inner joining but have not managed to solve the problem. For example:

```
select distinct
    DATE_STAMP,
    min(DATA_UPDATE_DATETIME) over (partition by DATE_STAMP),
    MIN_TEMP,
    MAX_TEMP,
from
    table
```

Comment: i've read most people prefer you put the sample and output as a text rather than image, so people can try to help you more easily , not wasting time typing the data themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by first building a table of the distinct DATE_STAMP values with the corresponding latest UPDATE value, and then join to that on the full table to get the desired result.

For example

```
WITH x AS
(
    SELECT DATE_STAMP, MAX(DATA_UPDATE_DATETIME) AS [MaxUpdate]
    FROM theTable
    GROUP BY DATE_STAMP
)
SELECT
x.DATE_STAMP,
x.MaxUpdate,
t.MIN_TEMP,
t.MAX_TEMP
FROM x
INNER JOIN theTable t
ON t.DATE_STAMP = x.DATE_STAMP
AND t.DATA_UPDATE_DATETIME = x.MaxUpdate
```

One thing you may want to consider is, what is your expectation if there happens to end up being two rows with the same DATE_STAMP and DATA_UPDATE_DATETIME values, but different MIN_TEMP and/or MAX_TEMP values (which could be possible, I guess, unless you've got some unique constraint on those columns, and are managing the data inserts/updates accordingly).  Otherwise, you've got a chance that you'll end up with more than one row for a particular DATE_STAMP / DATA_UPDATE_DATETIME combination

Comment: This is a perfect solution thank you Craig! I did end up having duplicates with rows with the same DATE_STAMP and DATA_UPDATE_DATETIME values. I am however pulling this into PowerQuery so can just remove duplicate rows there. Thanks again!